# Celery: Abort or revoke all tasks in a chord

Tags: python, task, celery, chord

I use the following setup with a Redis broker and backend:

`chord([A, A, A, ...])(B)`

- Task A does some checks. It uses `AbortableTask` as a base and regularly checks the `task.is_aborted()` flag.
- Task B notifies the user about the result of the calculation

The user has the possibility to abort the A tasks. Unfortunately, when calling `AbortableAsyncResult(task_a_id).abort()` on all the task A instances, only the active ones are being aborted. The status for tasks that have not been received yet by a worker are changed to `ABORTED`, but they're still processed and the `is_aborted()` flag returns False.

I could of course `revoke()` the pending tasks instead of `abort()`-ing them, but the problem is that in that case the chord body (task B) is not executed anymore.

How can all pending and running task A instances be stopped, while still ensuring that task B runs?

Answer (score 4):

Just get a list of id's of all the instances of `A` and stop them.

Consider this simple chord

```
from celery import chord 

my_chord = chord(a.si() for i in range(300))(b.si())
```

Now you can get a list of subtasks(all instaces of `a` task) from `my_chord` instance, using

```
for taks in my_chord.parent.subtasks:
    print(task.id)
```

Now you can do whatever you want to do with those task instaces. For example you can revoke all of the irrespective of their current state.

```
from celery.task.control import revoke

for task in my_chord.parent.subtasks:
    revoke(task.id, terminate=True)
```

`revoke` by default kills only pending tasks. But if you pass `terminate=True` to it, it kills the executing tasks also.

Also, chord's callback function will be called after all of its subtasks are executed successfully. Since you are cancelling the subtasks of chord, the call back function won't be called and the chord task results in failure. So, you have to retry the callback task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it's not the solution :) As described in the question, I'm already aborting/revoking the tasks by ID. The abort() doesn't work with pending tasks though, and revoke() prevents the callback from working. That's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Then you need to override `unlock_chord` so that the call back is called if subtasks results is either success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of chording the tasks themselves you may want to consider having the chords tasks that watch the A tasks.  What I mean by this is the chord would contain tasks that check the running tasks(A) every so often to see if they are done or revoked.  When all of those return successfully the chord with then chain into task B

Comment: That sounds like an interesting hack, but it also makes everything more complex :) I would rather hope that there's a built-in way in Celery to achieve this.

Comment: So the problem is the way celery works is a task will stay in the queue and be "active" unless it is revoked.  To my knowledge there is no way around this.  On the other end you need a chord to chain even if the tasks are revoked.  Again to my knowledge is not possible.

Comment: AbortableTasks (from the contrib package) *are* abortable (without killing the callback). The problem is that it only works with tasks that are running, not the ones that are pending.